# Laravel Auth::logout() Fail

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm just creating a basic application in Laravel 4 and i have one small problem.

My logout function is not working properly... well it works, *but*:

When a user is signed in and clicks the logout button the user i getting logged out but when i click on the browsers Back-button im getting back to the logged in page.

I'm using the `Auth::logout()`.
Does this method kill the session or does it have todo anything with the browsers cache?

How can i fix this?

My logout function:

```
public function getLogout(){

    if(Auth::check()){

        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::route('home');

    }
}
```

My routes:

```
/*
 * Authenticated users
 */

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {

    Route::get('success', array(

        'as' => 'success',
        'uses' => 'AccountController@getSuccess'

    ));


    Route::get('signout', array(
        'as' => 'signout',
        'uses' => 'AccountController@getLogout'
    ));

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is browser cache problem.

Try ...

```html
App::after(function($request, $response)
{    
  $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
  $response->headers->set('Pragma','no-cache');
  $response->headers->set('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the user away from the login page if he's already authenticated by simply putting an if-else statement to check that!

Comment: That won't do since browser still keeps the 'state' of previous browser on back button

Comment: Not true! Unless you're talking about Opera Web Browser. Chrome, Mozilla refresh previous pages and that's where you're supposed to check if the user is authenticated.

Comment: So Richie is should check if auth::check() in My succes page to?

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about in that English

Comment: @Richie: See tbuteler's answer above, that's what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour. The browser "remembers" loaded pages and doesn't reload them entirely when you hit the back button, so you'll still see the authentication-only pages even though you've been logged out properly. But any requests made to your app's restricted pages should now fail, because even though the browser is showing you code it rendered back when you were logged-in, it's no longer able to authenticate without your intervention. This is easy to verify:

1. Log in
2. Log out
3. Hit the back button
4. Refresh the page

You should now be prompted to log in rather than seeing the previous page.

Comment: tbuteler thats right!
The user is getting logged out and can go back but when he tries to do something like adding a contact the he gets redirected to the login form:).
Thanx!

Comment: How to set up, that after logout, page refresh? To save time, for this flow?

Answer (score 0):

@Spoofy, this is an issue with browser caching, 
read through [this](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=12955) link to fix this